# new Date(2012, 01,01) different then new Date(2012 01 01)

Tags: javascript

In chrome console,

`new Date('2012 01 01')` 
output: `Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

`new Date(2012, 01, 01)` 
output:
`Wed Feb 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

I'm really curious as to why this happens.

Anyone care to shed some light?

Comment: `new Date(2012 01 01)` results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant these:

```
new Date('2012 01 01');
new Date(2012, 01, 01); // Note the commas
```

And the reason is that the second example above uses [the version of the `Date` constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) that accepts numbers, rather than a string, and month numbers in JavaScript start with 0 = January. So `new Date(2012, 1, 1)` (the leading `0` in your examples is technically an error, but most engines allow it and treat the number as octal) is **February** 1st 2012.

The first version above uses the [`Date` constructor that takes a string](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) and parses it, and when parsing a date string, month numbers typically start with 1 = January. Note that the string you're asking Chrome to parse isn't in any format defined by the spec, and other engines may not parse it. In fact, until ECMAScript 5, there was **no** defined date string format (the `Date` constructor that accepted a string was defined as accepting whatever `toString` output, but neither was actually specified). ECMAScript 5 added a simplified version of ISO-8601. But in the wild, every engine in the last decade has supported date strings in the form `yyyy/mm/dd` (but not necessarily the now-specified `yyyy-mm-dd`).

Comment: "the leading 0 is technically an error" --- this sounds strange. Does ECMAscript define non-zero positive numbers as something like `+?[1-9]\d*`?

Comment: @zerkms: `0` is a valid decimal number in JavaScript, `01` is not. A numeric literal can only start with a `0` if it's `0`, or if the `0` is followed by an `x` and the remainder is in hex. [§7.8.3 of the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) covers this. Many JavaScript engines extend the definition of a JavaScript numeric literal to allow a leading zero to indicate octal (as many other languages in the same syntactic family, derived from the B language, do), but it is not standard and is expressly forbidden in strict mode.

Comment: @zerkms: And re-reading the regex in your question, another (and rather shorter!) way to put my reply would be: Yes, for decimal (as opposed to hex). :-)

Comment: that's offtop, sorry, but I cannot see how it's possible to match `-7.3` according to those rules.

Comment: @zerkms: Not following you... You said your regex only applied to "non-zero positive numbers" which is why I added the note saying "yes." :-) Re the link: If I'm reading the syntax right, `-7.3` is a [unary `-` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7) followed by a [numeric literal](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3). I'd never noticed before that §7.8.3 doesn't define negative numbers with fractional portions, but does define negative integers (via the *SignedInteger* bit). How odd! But the unary `-` deals with it.

Comment: yep, that's explains everything. "How odd" - not actually, as long as it is defined especially for exponent. Well, thanks again ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah, how could I miss the 0 based thing.